# Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem here. I keep getting this error which is number of bound variables does not match number of tokens. I double check my code and doesn't seems to have an error on it. Anyway, I am new to these PDO thing.

This is the code how I call the data from database to echo in the form

```
if(isset($_GET['idstudent'], $_GET['idbook'])){
$_SESSION['link']=$_GET['idstudent'];
$_SESSION['link2']=$_GET['idbook'];
$sessionidstudent = $_SESSION['link'];
$sessionidbook = $_SESSION['link2']; }  


$query = " 
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM viewlibrary
    WHERE 
        id = :sessionidstudent AND
        serialno = :sessionidbook

"; 

$query_params = array( 
    ':sessionidstudent' => $_SESSION['link'],
    ':sessionidbook' => $_SESSION['link2'] 
); 

try 
{ 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
}
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
}
$r=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    ?>
```

This is my HTML code

```
<form action="editpage.php" method="post" class="login, reminder">
<p>Student Matric Number:
    <input type="text" class="login-input" name="addmatricno" id="addmatricno" value="<?php echo $r['matricno'] ?>" placeholder="Enter student matric number">
    Student Name:
    <input type="text" class="login-input" name="addname" id="addname" value="<?php echo $r['studentname'] ?>" placeholder="Enter student name">
    Programme:
    <input type="text" class="login-input" name="addprogramme" id="addprogramme" value="<?php echo $r['programme'] ?>" placeholder="Enter student programme">
    Education Level:

    <?php

        if($r['education_level'] == "PHD"){
            echo '<select name="selectedulevel" id="selectedulevel" class="login-input">';
            echo '<option disabled>Please select education level</option>';
            echo '<option value="PHD" selected>PHD</option>';
            echo '<option value="MASTER">MASTER</option>';
            echo '<option value="PHD">DEGREE</option></p></select>';
        }
        else if($r['education_level'] == "MASTER"){
            echo '<select name="selectedulevel" id="selectedulevel" class="login-input">';
            echo '<option disabled>Please select education level</option>';
            echo '<option value="PHD">PHD</option>';
            echo '<option value="MASTER" selected>MASTER</option>';
            echo '<option value="PHD">DEGREE</option></p></select>';
        }
        else{
            echo '<select name="selectedulevel" id="selectedulevel" class="login-input">';
            echo '<option disabled>Please select education level</option>';
            echo '<option value="PHD">PHD</option>';
            echo '<option value="MASTER">MASTER</option>';
            echo '<option value="PHD" selected>DEGREE</option></p></select>';
        }

    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="updatestudent" id="updatestudent" value="Update Student" class="login-submit" style = "width: 20%; text-align: center">
```

Last but not least, my query code.

```
$query = " 
        UPDATE student
            SET
                matricno = :addmatricno,
                studentname = :addname,
                programme = :addprogramme,
                education_level = :selectedulevel
            WHERE
                id = :sessionidstudent
    "; 

    $query_params = array( 
        ':addmatricno' => $_POST['addmatricno'], 
        ':addname' => $_POST['addname'], 
        ':addprogramme' => $_POST['addprogramme'], 
        ':selectedulevel' => $_POST['selectedulevel']
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        // Execute the query to create the user 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        //$stmt->bindValue(':sessionidstudent',$sessionidstudent);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    }


    // This redirects the user back to the login page after they register 
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Info updated successful.")';
    echo '</script>'; 
    header("Refresh: 0; updatebooks.php"); 
    die();
```

note: $db refer to `$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);` where I put on other file and i can sure my connection to database has no problem at all.
I have check my code many times but still getting the same error.

Comment: Forget to bind`sessionidstudent` in update query!!

Comment: Yeah i forgot that. sorry. embarrassing. Although i didn't know the variable after WHERE clause need to be put in query params as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query params variable you forgot to add the `:sessionidstudent` in the update query,  add that and the error will be gone

Comment: .....oh this is embarrassing. i shouldn't post this problem. However thanks to you at least i know that that variable after WHERE clause need to be put in query params as well. I didnt know that. Thanks and sorry for the trouble :)

Comment: It's fine,  you're welcome, if it did fix your problem, click on the checkmark icon to mark your question as answered! Have a nice day!